# Jenkins ssh into Ubuntu instance, permission error with pem, even with chmod 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

i try to run a command from my local Jenkins
`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/xxx/tools/xma00.pem ubuntu@10.xxx.xxx.xxx`

After I click the build, the Jenkins output says I have permission error, even I did chmod 400 xma00.pem

> Load key "/Users/xxx/tools/xma00.pem": Permission denied Received
>   disconnect from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22:2: Too many authentication
>   failures Authentication failed.

Comment: How many entries are in `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: @helloV Hello, I don't know how to check that. I add ssh-add -l at the beginning, I got error like Load key "/Users/xxx/tools/xma00.pem": Permission denied
Received disconnect from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Authentication failed.

Comment: Try: `ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/xxx/tools/xma00.pem ubuntu@10.xxx.xxx.xxx`. I added `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes`

Comment: @helloV I tried, same error.

Comment: I should have mentioned earlier. Adding `-vvv` will output more usefule information. `ssh -vvv -o ....`